# Regular Expressions not working Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression to match " [stuff] ". There can be escape characters, but as long as there is an even number of them, they do nothing.  My regex is:

```
(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\".*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\"
```

and it will match when the second quote has an even number of `\`s, ie (`"a daf asd \\"`)

but not when the first quote does (ie `\\" adf "`)

anyone have any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: I hope you're using raw string literals to define your regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following, if I am clear on what you are trying to do.

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*".*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"
```

Regular expression explanation:

```
(?<!\\)    Matches if the preceding char is not a backslash
(?:\\\\)*  Matches 0 or more occurrences of two backslashes
"          Matches a double quote
.*?        Matches any character except \n (0 or more times)

Repeat lines 1-3
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bY9oM7)